# @@ clause in t-sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

What does mean `@@` symbols  before some variable in t-sql stored procedure? thanks!

Comment: prefix for reserved SQL Server Variables

Comment: I think this is worth reading http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39131/Global-Variables-in-SQL-Server

Answer (score 1):

The @@ is the prefix that system variables use, e.g.

```
@@VERSION
```

You can create you own variables, that have a single @ prefix, e.g.

```
DECLARE @id INT
```

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN

> The names of some Transact-SQL system functions begin with two at
>   signs (@@). Although in earlier versions of Microsoft SQL Server, the
>   @@functions are referred to as global variables, they are not
>   variables and do not have the same behaviors as variables. The
>   @@functions are system functions, and their syntax usage follows the
>   rules for functions.

So @@ are not variables but  provided by SQL Server to represent a specific value to server or session.

Eg.

```
SELECT @@ERROR -- gives error status of previously executed statement. 
--If statement succeeds , it contains value 0 else it contains last error number generated by system.
```

Answer (score 0):

- Global variable names begin with a @@ prefix.
- It is maintained by the server constantly.
- system-defined functions.

  **Example:**

**@@ROWCOUNT

@@VERSION

@@CONNECTIONS**